# Firebase Function Gen2 not deploying

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I have a bunch of firebase functions Gen1 working right now, and today I tried to add a new function using Gen2, my plan is to upgrade all my current Gen1 functions... but I've got the following error when deploying:

> shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit
>
> Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

If I coment out my Gen2 function, everything just deploys flawlessly, so I assume it's a problem of my Gen2 function.

Here's my Gen 2 function:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {value: true});

const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/lib/firestore");

const db = getFirestore();

const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

export const crmGroupRecipientsCounter = onDocumentWritten("marketing/crm/recipients/{recipientID}", async (event:any) => {
  // Get an object with the current document va/lues.
  // If the document does not exist, it was deleted
  if (event.data) {
    // const document = event.data.after.data();
    const id = event.data.after.id;
    const counter = await getGroupCount(id);
    updateGroupCounter(id, counter).then((r) => null);
  }
});

const getGroupCount = async (id:string) => {
  const recipients = db.collection("marketing").doc("crm").collection("recipients");
  const snapshot = await recipients.where("guid", "==", id).where("disabled", "==", false).get();
  if (!snapshot.empty) {
    return snapshot.size;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
};

const updateGroupCounter = async (id:string, counter:number) => {
  await db.collection("marketing").doc("crm").collection("recipients").doc(id).update({
    counter: counter,
  });
};
```

Also this is my `index.ts` file where I recall all my functions:

```
// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
// export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

import {initializeApp, cert} from "firebase-admin/app";

// const {initializeApp, cert} = require("firebase-admin/app");

const serviceAccount = require("../env/serviceAccount.json");

initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
});

import {crmGroupRecipientsCounter} from "./actions/marketing-module/countGroupRecipients";
exports.crmGroupRecipientsCounter = crmGroupRecipientsCounter;

const getDailyRate = require("./actions/get-daily-rates");
exports.getDailyRate = getDailyRate.getDailyRate;

const sendMail = require("./actions/send-mails");
exports.postmark = sendMail.postmark;
exports.cronMail = sendMail.cronMail;

const manageUser = require("./actions/manage-guests");
exports.manageUser = manageUser.manageUser;

const bulkReservations = require("./actions/bulk-create-reservations");
exports.bulkCreateReservations = bulkReservations.bulkCreateReservations;

const cFixer = require("./actions/credentials-fixer");
exports.credentialsFixer = cFixer.fixCredentials;

const getWeather = require("./actions/get-weather");
exports.getWeather = getWeather.getWeather;

const reservationTracker = require("./actions/track-last-reservation");
exports.reservationTracker = reservationTracker.reservationTracker;
```

This is my `firebase.json` file

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "codebase": "default",
    "runtime": "nodejs20",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/pwa",
    "site": "my-site",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "service-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and finally my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "es6-promise-pool": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "indicadores-economicos-bccr": "^2.0.1",
    "openweather-apis": "^4.5.0",
    "postmark": "^3.0.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my current development environment:

```
OS:                        **Mac OS Ventura**
Computer:                  **Macbook Pro M1 Pro**
Node version:              **v20.4.0**
Firebase Tools version:    **firebase-tools@12.4.4**
```

Before I tried with `node v18.5`, but I had the exact same problem, and `node v20` should work according to the documentation.

Please note that I don't fully understand how to write well structured firebase functions, it's been a little confusing, so if you see something I could do better, you are more than welcome to suggest.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Tried commenting out that `__esModule` line from the top of your gen 2 function's file?

Comment: You've also got a floating promise where you call `updateGroupCounter`, it should have `return` or `await` before the call.

Comment: Additionally, you should use [`Query#count()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query#_google_cloud_firestore_Query_count_member_1_) (usage: `yourQuery.count().get()`) if possible for `getGroupCount()` instead of using `Query#get()` and returning the size. It is more efficient in both network traffic and processing speed.

Comment: @samthecodingman I did try with and without the __esModule line, same result, thanks for pointing out my mistakes I did already change it based on your comments... though I'm still unable to deploy because of this weird error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found out that the error was related to my imports:

So instead of importing this:

```
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/lib/firestore");
```

I had to do it this way:

```
import {getFirestore} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

Somehow the path is not correct in the first approach, even though it does exist in the node_modules package path.

So in short, the problem was the import path. If you use require and you are using typescript, I've noted that it won't get types, so in order to get types, use the import approach instead of destructured require.

Hopefully, this could be worth a try for anyone struggling with this error.

PD: I tried to migrate my Gen1 functions to Gen2 in the same codebase; this was a nightmare. What worked perfectly for me was creating two separate codebases.